# Adding character to a string

Tags: c++

I got one problem.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string word;
    cout << "Enter word: ";
    cin >> word;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        if (word.at(i) == 'a') {
            word.at(i) += 'r';
        }
        i++;
    } while(i < word.size());
    cout << word << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

All I want to do, is if input is for example: `racket`, the output should be `rarcket`.
In other words, each time character `'a'` is located, the program should add character `'r'` to it.

I think the program gets the ASCII code value of each letter and then it does addition operation. It gives me some strange letter.

Comment: Your code is effectively setting the character at `i` to `'a' + 'r'`. [std::string::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at)

Comment: What you want to do is [*insert*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) a character at a specific position.

Comment: `+=` does not magically insert a letter into the string, but it adds `'r'` to `'a'`

Comment: You should use the [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) when accepting strings from a standard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [string::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/).

Here is the code that will work for your example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word;
    cout << "Enter word: ";
    cin >> word;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        if (word.at(i) == 'a') {
            word.insert(i + 1, "r");
        }
        i++;
    } while (i<word.size());
    cout << word << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For a single character 'r' would be advisable.

Comment: @Janosimas Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a [version of `std::string::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) accepting an index *and* a single character, though.

Comment: half-truth, there is no version for index and single char but there is iterator and char. You could use begin()+index ou use iterator instead of index.

Comment: @Janosimas That's why I emphasized the "and" in there. It's pretty much the exact truth. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You are not inserting anything into your string. Instead you actually call the `+=` operator of the *character element*, not the one of the *string* (which can only append at the end anyway).

What you actually want to do is ***insert* an element into the string**. The easiest way to do that in your example would be something like replacing

```
word.at(i)+='r';
```

with

```
word.insert(word.begin()+(++i), 'r');
```

which inserts an `'r'` behind the `'a'` you found.

However, notice that inserting characters in this way might invalidate any iterators into the string due to possible reallocation. This isn't a problem in your case, since you use an index-based iteration and check against the (possibly increased) size of the string in each iteration, but it is something worth to keep in mind.

Comment: If you're going to be flashy then you may as well go the whole hog with `word.begin() + ++i`.

Comment: @Bathsheba If I was going to be flashy than I'd do away with the entire thing and improve stuff like using `at` for access instead of `[]`, as well as a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop and whatever other entirely unrelated problems the original code has. Instead I tried to work it into his existing example as easily as possible and leave him figuring out any unrelated best practice issues to another day.

Comment: Yes it's a nice answer. Have an upvote on account of the fact that I've pinched your expression. Naturally the cool cats would work backwards from the end of the string to minimise shifts.

Answer (score 1):

`word.at(i) += 'r';` is changing the character at position `i` to a different value. It is **not** inserting `r` into the string.

If `char` is `signed` on your platform, then depending on your *encoding*, the behaviour of your program is *undefined* as adding `'r'` to `'a'` might overflow a `signed` type! `'a'` and `'r'` are simply numeric *literals* of `char` type. This notation is provided for convenience in order to make code clear and portable.

If you want to *insert* an actual character then use `std::string::insert`:

```
word.insert(word.begin() + ++i, 'r');
```

would do it, I've taken care to increment `i` again to skip over the character just added.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert

Answer (score 0):

```
if(word.at(i)=='a'){
    word.at(i)+='r';
}
```

The above code does not do what you think it should. It adds the numeric representation of `'a'` with `'r'` and stores it at index `i`. Assuming the result fits into the type of `char` on your platform.

You can [`std::string::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) into a specific position in the string, but its **probably better** to just use an new string: - You may copy each character of the string to another string (appending an extra character on the fly).

```
std::string word;
std::string newWord;
std::cout << "Enter word: ";
std::cin >> word;
for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    newWord += word[i];
    if(word[i] == 'a')
        newWord += 'r';
}
std::cout << newWord << std::endl;
```

EDIT:
As noted, the above works, because `std::string` has an overloaded `+=` operator for `char`

Comment: Worth noting that this works since `std::string` has an overloaded `+=` to a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

insert after first occurrence

```
auto search = 'a';
auto insert = 'b';
for(auto i = word.begin(), e = word.end(); i < e; ++i)
  if(*i == search) {
    word.insert(i + 1, insert);
    return;
  }
```

insert after each occurrence

```
auto search = 'a';
auto insert = 'b';
for(auto i = word.begin(), e = word.end(); i < e; ++i)
  if(*i == search) {
    i = word.insert(i + 1, insert);
    e = word.end();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should include the header `<string>` explicitly

```
#include <string>
```

because according to the C++ Standard it is not necessary that the header `<iostream>` includes the header `<string>`.

You could use the method `insert` of the class `std::string` as others are suggesting. However this approach is inefficient because there can be many moves of substrings and reallocations of the memory occupied by the string.

In my opinion a straightforward approach will be more efficient.

Here is a demonstrative program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string word;

    std::cout << "Enter word: ";

    std::cin >> word;

    std::string::size_type n = std::count(word.begin(), word.end(), 'a');

    if (n)
    {
        auto m = word.size();
        word.resize( m + n);

        for (auto i = m; n != 0; )
        {
            if (word[--i] == 'a')
            {
                word[i + n--] = 'r';
            }
            word[i + n] = word[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << word << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you do

```
 word.at(i) = 'r';
```

you are actually changing the character at position *i* to a different value.

if you need to append/add a string at a given index in the word object then do

```
word.insert(1, "!");
```

example:

```
std::string word{"HelloXoce"};

std::cout << "Word: " << word << std::endl;
word.at(0) = 'X';
std::cout << "Word: " << word << std::endl;
word.insert(1, "!");
std::cout << "Word: " << word << std::endl;
```